# OneNote for Android - Offline API?

Tags: android, onenote

I'm looking at developing a to-do list Android widget that draws from a OneNote to-do list.

While most Android phones are permanently connected to the internet via 3G or LTE, many tablets are still WiFi only and will not have internet connectivity when on the go. I could, in this situation, store the data that I receive from the API locally and queue any changes made for the next time the tablet is available online, but there's a problem with this solution. What if the user edits the same to-do list via the OneNote app?

What I'm wondering is if there's any way that my widget can talk to the OneNote app when the device is offline.

It seems that OneNote's data files are stored in a location that needs a rooted device to access externally, so interacting with them seems to be not an option. How can I achieve my goal?

I'm new to Android development, but I think Android's Intents system might be a solution. Does OneNote expose any Intents?

Thanks,

YM

(Apologies if the tone in this post seems strange, I originally posted it on [answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/) but was told that it belongs here instead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have Android client APIs at this time, and talking to the local files isn't a good idea, as the app isn't expecting them to change outside of its control.  We would like to get round to client APIs, across all platforms, but its unlikely to happen in the next six months at least.  This would be a good request to post on our [uservoice](https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-apis) site to see if there's broader interest.    Please do include the scope of the methods you'd need.

Comment: Posted to uservoice here: https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-apis/suggestions/7048554-provide-client-apis-to-allow-offline-editing-witho